# Evaluate $\int\limits_0^{\infty}e^{-x}|\sin (\frac{π}{4}-x)|dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I have to evaluate the integral :

> $$\int\limits_0^{\infty}e^{-x}|\sin (\frac{π}{4}-x)|dx$$

By wolfram alpha :

> $$\int\limits_0^{\infty}e^{-x}|\sin (\frac{π}{4}-x)|dx≈0,476531..$$

$$\sin (\frac{π}{4}-x)>0\implies x\in ]πn-\frac{7π}{4},πn-\frac{3π}{4}[,n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

$$\sin (\frac{π}{4}-x)<0\implies x\in ]2πn+\frac{π}{4},2πn+\frac{5π}{4}[,n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

So I can't split integral

Normally I would show my work so far, however, I don't even know where to start with this question!

Comment: Have you tried splitting it into two infinite sums?

Comment: @saulspatz How sir ? Can you give me a Hint!

Comment: One sum would represent the integral over the union of the intervals where the integrand is non-negative and the other would be the negative of the integral over the union of the intervals where the integrand is negative.

Comment: @saulspatz please explain more how i use sum here?

Comment: I posted an answer.  It's little more concise than my comment, since I realized I could just take the absolute value instead of using two sums.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\left|\sin\left(\frac\pi4-x\right)\right|\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\left|\sin\left(x-\frac\pi4\right)\right|\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{-\pi/4}^\infty e^{\pi/4-u}\left|\sin{u}\right|\mathrm{d}u\\
&=e^{\pi/4}\int_{-\pi/4}^\pi e^{-u}\left|\sin{u}\right|\mathrm{d}u+\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{\pi/4}\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} e^{-u}\left|\sin{u}\right|\mathrm{d}u\\
&=e^{\pi/4}\int_{-\pi/4}^\pi e^{-u}\left|\sin{u}\right|\mathrm{d}u+\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{\pi/4}\left|\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} e^{-u}\sin{u}\,\mathrm{d}u\right|
\end{align}\\
$$

Can you finish it?

Comment: Thank you very much sir i find : $\frac{(-1)^(n)}{2}e^{-(1 + 2 n) π}(e^{n π} + e^{(1 + n) π)}$ its easy I think just i use $\sum (-1)^{n}x^{n}=\frac{1}{1+x}$

Comment: @EllenEllen You're very welcome.  I didn't work it out past the point shown above.  You can check your answer against the numerical value you got from Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Can you explain why $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{\pi/4}\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} e^{-u}\left|\sin{u}\right|\mathrm{d}u=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{\pi/4}\left|\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} e^{-u}\sin{u}\,\mathrm{d}u\right| $

Comment: @EllenEllen Because the sine function doesn't change sign on the interval $[n\pi,(n+1)\pi]$.